# Unsure of why approach to evaluation limit is incorrect

Tags: limits

I have the function
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x\sin\left(\frac1x\right) & x\text{ is rational}\\
x^2 & x\text{ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$

I found the limit as x approaches 0 to be 0 by considering a sequence of rational and irrational numbers. This was a past exam question but the answer hasn't been published and the feedback states that:

"some students considered two different sequences
converging to 0 (one of rational numbers and another one of irrational numbers), they studied the
limit of the sequences given by the image through the function f of these two sequences, showed
that the limit of these sequences was zero, and deduced incorrectly that the limit of the function
at the point 0 was 0."

So I'm unsure of why this argument would be incorrect as questions regarding similar functions include the same sequence based method

Comment: Not "a sequence...", but "any sequence...".

Comment: What level of rigor are you working at? Is this a calculus class? Real analysis? Are you expected to construct a $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ proof?

Comment: It's better if you say why you think this argument is *correct* - are you applying some theorem? Which one?  That way you'll get a more helpful explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure of the level of detail your instructor wants, but by definition, for some real number $L$,
$\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = L$ precisely when, for all sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$.

It seems like your instructor suggests that there were student solutions which looked at *two* sequences (one of rational numbers and one of irrational numbers) tending towards $0$, rather than all possible sequences. Notice the difference between the following statements:

- For every sequence $x_n\to0$, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$.
- For every sequence of *rational* numbers $x_n\to0$, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$, *and* for every sequence of *irrational* numbers $x_n\to0$, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$.
- For a particular sequence of *rational* numbers $x_n\to0$, say $\left(\frac1n\right)_n$, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$, and a particular sequence of *irrational* numbers, say $\left(\frac{1}{\pi n}\right)_n$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$.

Your professor is likely not satisfied by answers which do not exhibit a student's understanding of the distinction between these; only the first of these bullets is the definition of convergence to $L$, so if you want to check a different condition, you should probably apply a theorem, otherwise it will not be convincing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a counterexample, where your method does not work. Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by:
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0& \text{if } x=\frac{a}{2^n}\text{ for some $a>0$ odd and }n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}\\
1& \text{if } x=\frac{a}{2^n}\text{ for some $a<0$ odd and }n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}\\
0& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then considering some sequence of irrational numbers tending to 0, and the sequence of rational numbers $\frac{1}{2^n}$ tending to 0, we might incorrectly conclude that the limit of the function at 0 is 0. However, if we consider the sequence $\frac{-1}{2^n}$, the function tends to 1 as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

However, if you could show that for ALL sequences converging to 0 that are either entirely rational or entirely irrational, that $f$ converges to 0 on each sequence, then it would be true that the limit of $f$ at 0 is indeed 0. You can prove this by contradiction (assume not, then some sequence exists s.t. $|f|$ is always $>\epsilon$, then extract a subsequence that is entirely rational or irrational).